# Constraint Linear regression in finance

Tags: linear-model

Below you can find the problem that I am trying to understand. My main problem is to understand where do the reparametrization that they propose come from. Alternatively I have try to connect it with the constraint LS KKT solution but I do not see the connection.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbf{r}_t=\left(\begin{array}{l:l}
\mathbf{1} & \mathbf{B}_i
\end{array}\right) \mathbf{f}_{m i, t}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_t, \quad t=1,2, \cdots, T \\
& =\mathbf{B}_{m i} \mathbf{f}_{m i, t}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_t \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\mathbf{B}_{m i}$ is an $N \times(K+1)$ matrix with $\mathbf{B}_i$ an $N \times K$ matrix of $1^{\prime} s$ and $0^{\prime} s$ representing $K$ industry sectors, with each stock belonging to one and only one sector over the given time interval, and
$$
\mathbf{f}_{m i, t}=\left(f_{0, t}, f_{1, t},, f_{2, t}, \cdots, f_{K, t}\right)^{\prime} .
$$

As such the matrix B is rank deficient with rank K instead of K+1. Consequently the use of LS to fit the above model for each time period does not lead to a unique solution. One solution is to impose a constraint:

$$
f_{1, t}+f_{2, t}+\cdots+f_{K, t}=0 .
$$

This can be accomplished with the reparameterization (this is where I don't understand)
$$
\mathbf{f}_{m i, t}=\mathbf{R}_{m i} \mathbf{g}_{m i, t}
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}_t=\mathbf{B}_{m i} \mathbf{R}_{m i} \mathbf{g}_{m i, t}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_t
$$

where
$$
\mathbf{R}_{m i}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{I}_K \\
\boldsymbol{a}^{\prime}
\end{array}\right) \sim(K+1) \times K
$$
$$
\boldsymbol{a}^{\prime}=(0,-1,-1, \cdots,-1) \sim K \times 1
$$
$$
\mathbf{g}_{m i, t}=\left(g_{1, t}, g_{2, t}, \cdots, g_{K, t}\right)^{\prime} .
$$

The model (9) now has a unique least-squares solution $\hat{\mathbf{g}}_t$, and it is easy to check that (8) insures that the constraint (7) is satisfied.

Comment: Although the ornate notation obscures the question, it *looks* like you are asking about [dummy variable coding.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+variable+coding)  Would that be an accurate interpretation?

Comment: yes it is an accurate description

Comment: Have you found answers to your question in the link, then?

Comment: I have found my answer in an econometric textbook now I am confused about the interpretation of the constraint with regards to the dummy variables. I am going to do another post about it